# Sum of related objects across 2 FK to the same table, with conditions

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models:

```py
class User(Model):
    ...

class Message(Model):
    sender = ForeignKey(User, CASCADE, 'sent_msgs')
    receiver = ForeignKey(User, CASCADE, 'rcvd_msgs')
    ignored = BooleanField()
```

I'm trying to annotate a queryset of Users with a sum total of their related messages, i.e. sum of both `sent_msgs` and `rcvd_msgs`. Additionally, any Message with `ignored=True` should be ignored.

I can do this with `RawSQL` fairly simply, using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT("messages_message"."id")
FROM "messages_message"
WHERE "messages_message"."ignored" = FALSE
  AND (
    "messages_message"."sender_id" = "users_user"."id"
    OR
    "messages_message"."receiver_id" = "users_user"."id"
  )
```

```py
queryset = queryset.annotate(msgs_count=RawSQL(that_query_above))
```

Is there a way to do this without using `RawSQL`?

Comment: I think you should use conditional expression of django where you can use `if` `elif` `else` logic within filters, annotations, aggregations, and updates as stated in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions)

Comment: @dipbazz Tried that a lot, but couldn't get it to work. The problem was that they were producing two `JOIN`s instead of a subquery, which resulted in more rows than there actually are.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a [**`Subquery`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) here:

```
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery, Q

User.objects.annotate(
    msgs_count=Subquery(
        Message.objects.filter(
            Q(sender_id=OuterRef('pk')) | Q(receiver_id=OuterRef('pk')),
            ignored=False
        ).order_by().values('ignored').annotate(cn=Count('*')).values('cn')
    )
)
```

This then produces a query like:

```
SELECT auth_user.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cn
        FROM message U0
        WHERE (U0.sender_id = auth_user.id OR U0.receiver_id = auth_user.id)
            AND U0.ignored = False)
        GROUP BY U0.ignored
    ) AS msgs_count
FROM auth_user
```

Comment: Ok, this looks like it could work (and I didn't know about `Subquery`, thanks!), but with actual data the query raises an error: `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: @frnhr: did you added the `.values('pk')` at the end of the subquery parameter?

Comment: yeap, I did. The query itself chokes (testing directly on the DB, no python)

Comment: @frnhr: ah, I found a way to circumvent that.